# PCA - low variable loadings on first component

Tags: pca

I perform a PCA on 40 variables & keep all components with a min. eigenvalue of 1 (which results in a total of 5 components) - STATA gives me the following output:

```
>pca *all variables*, mineigen(1)


 Component |   Eigenvalue   Difference         Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
           Comp1 |      29.0991      26.3849             0.7275       0.7275
           Comp2 |      2.71421      .672651             0.0679       0.7953
           Comp3 |      2.04156      .803292             0.0510       0.8464
           Comp4 |      1.23826      .201987             0.0310       0.8773
           Comp5 |      1.03628      .170083             0.0259       0.9032


Principal components (eigenvectors) 


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Variable |    Comp1     Comp2     Comp3     Comp4     Comp5 | Unexplained 
    -------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------
 R_wt1_GLR~13 |   0.0036    0.2762   -0.1522    0.4151    0.3403 |       .4118 
   R_wt7_FO14 |   0.0689    0.0353   -0.2479   -0.2684    0.3559 |       .5124 
    std_GL~24 |   0.1825   -0.0001    0.0000   -0.0959   -0.0131 |       .0191 
    std_GLR~6 |   0.1712    0.0201    0.1849   -0.1215   -0.0321 |      .05681 
    std_GLR~8 |   0.1822    0.0119   -0.0235   -0.0713   -0.0102 |      .02624 
    wt1_GL~13 |   0.0263    0.4621    0.3717    0.0753    0.1531 |      .08684 
    wt1_GL~24 |   0.1819    0.0148    0.0268   -0.0981   -0.0225 |       .0222 
    wt1_GLR~6 |   0.1615    0.0390    0.2516   -0.1209   -0.0765 |      .08364 
    wt1_GLR~8 |   0.1815    0.0138    0.0119   -0.0902   -0.0269 |      .02935 
    wt1_GLR~9 |   0.0192    0.4457    0.3554    0.1194    0.1716 |       .1442 
    wt2_GL~24 |   0.1832   -0.0186   -0.0229    0.0034   -0.0486 |      .01839 
    wt2_GLR~3 |   0.0133    0.4138   -0.1428    0.0898   -0.4108 |       .3035 
    wt2_GLR~5 |   0.1828    0.0111    0.0114   -0.0629   -0.0511 |      .01971 
    wt2_GLR~6 |   0.1758    0.0030    0.1206   -0.0245   -0.0877 |      .06209 
    wt2_GLR~8 |   0.1826   -0.0273   -0.0410    0.0064   -0.0405 |      .02255 
    wt3_GLR~5 |   0.1809    0.0139    0.0323   -0.0957   -0.0601 |      .02963 
    wt3_GLR~6 |   0.1601    0.0576    0.2214   -0.1942   -0.1267 |      .08216 
    wt4_GL~24 |   0.1801    0.0136    0.0055   -0.1630    0.0246 |      .02207 
    wt4_GLR~5 |   0.1823    0.0107    0.0143   -0.0683   -0.0444 |      .02444 
    wt4_GLR~6 |   0.1620    0.0340    0.1740   -0.1918   -0.0349 |       .1246 
    wt5_GL~24 |   0.1793   -0.0337    0.0051    0.0841   -0.0665 |      .04766 
    wt5_GLR~8 |   0.1783   -0.0447    0.0179    0.1118   -0.0840 |      .04559 
    wt7_GL~24 |   0.1823   -0.0213    0.0006   -0.0537    0.0023 |      .02847 
    wt7_GLR~5 |   0.1835   -0.0185   -0.0012   -0.0256   -0.0322 |      .01707 
    wt7_GLR~8 |   0.1815   -0.0169   -0.0189   -0.0773    0.0129 |      .03221 
      wt8_FO9 |   0.0530    0.2385   -0.4929   -0.0310   -0.2132 |       .2196 
    wt8_GLR~8 |   0.1813   -0.0263    0.0131    0.0054   -0.0326 |      .03966 
     wt1_FO10 |  -0.0476   -0.4309    0.1862    0.0542    0.0003 |       .3557 
      wt2_FO4 |   0.1184    0.2212   -0.3360   -0.2154   -0.0222 |       .1705 
     wt2_LM24 |   0.1768   -0.0569   -0.0708    0.1434    0.1202 |      .03092 
      wt2_LM8 |   0.1760   -0.0574   -0.0765    0.1076    0.0800 |      .05662 
     wt4_LM24 |   0.1802   -0.0441   -0.0376    0.1390    0.0486 |      .02063 
      wt4_LM6 |   0.1576   -0.0866    0.0472    0.3475    0.0284 |       .1015 
      wt4_LM8 |   0.1803   -0.0384   -0.0418    0.0807    0.0302 |      .03795 
     wt5_LM24 |   0.1805   -0.0226   -0.0490    0.0956    0.0570 |      .03072 
     wt6_LM24 |   0.1773   -0.0542   -0.0484    0.2013    0.0248 |        .022 
      wt6_LM6 |   0.1606   -0.0935    0.0132    0.3480    0.0376 |      .07385 
     wt7_LM24 |   0.1768   -0.0383   -0.0915    0.1524    0.0798 |      .03353 
      wt7_LM8 |   0.1769   -0.0521   -0.0889    0.1051    0.0278 |      .05139 
     wt8_LM10 |   0.0656    0.0088   -0.0737   -0.2891    0.6266 |       .3532 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was wondering why the loading for all variables on Comp1 is so low (basically for all <0.2), whereas I have 4 variables for Comp2, Comp3 and Comp5 and 3 variables for Comp4 which are all >0.3. Is there any good explanation for that?

Thank´s for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert and I've only played with PCA in openCV, but your results to me say that there is a ***heavy*** functional relationship between your variables.

The fact that the eigenvalue for the first component (and first component only) once normalized retains %72 of the original variance plays into this.

(It is also almost 11 times more significant than the next eigenvector direction.)

This potentially implies that the other axes are simply sampling noise rather than your signals (or signal) of interest...